# Использование вложенных форм Django с many to many

Tags: django

Пытаюсь сделать из 2х связанных моделей создать вложенную форму для создания заявки. Для связи моделей "заявка" и "контейнер" использована связь many to many, т.к. в одной заявке может быть несколько контейнеров, а один контейнер может относится к нескольким заявкам.

До переделки под inlineformset у меня рендерилась форма заявки, но поле контейнера было полем выбора контейнера из другой таблицы. А мне надо создавать контейнер в момент заведения заявки.
Ниже переделанный код собранный по гайдам.

## models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Container(models.Model):
TWENTY_FEET = '20'
FOURTY_FEET = '40'
FEET_CHOISES = ((TWENTY_FEET, '20'), (FOURTY_FEET, '40'))
container_size = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=FEET_CHOISES, default=TWENTY_FEET)
container_number = models.CharField(verbose_name='Контейнер', max_length=11, default='XXXX1234567')


class Order(models.Model):
NO_RELEASE = 'релиза нет'
RELEASE = 'релиз есть'
HOME_BL = 'сквозной'
TELEX_CHOICES = ((NO_RELEASE, 'релиза нет'), (RELEASE, 'релиз есть'), (HOME_BL, 'сквозной'))
order_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата заявки')
transport_ref = models.CharField(verbose_name='Референс транпортной', max_length=10)
broker_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Брокер', max_length=10)
partner = models.ManyToManyField(ClientCompany)
supplier = models.ManyToManyField(Supplier)
goods = models.CharField(verbose_name='Товар', max_length=24)
invoice = models.CharField(verbose_name='Инвойс', max_length=24, default='invoice')
terms = models.CharField(verbose_name='Условия поставки', max_length=3)
release = models.CharField(verbose_name='Телекс', choices=TELEX_CHOICES, default=NO_RELEASE, max_length=10)
pol = models.CharField(verbose_name='POL', max_length=24)
pod = models.CharField(verbose_name='POD', max_length=24)
delivery_place = models.CharField(verbose_name='Пункт назначения', max_length=24)
ready = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата готовности')
shipping_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата погрузки')
container = models.ManyToManyField(Container)
departure_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата выхода')
port_arrival_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата подхода')
documents_get_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата получения документов')
gtd_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата подачи ГТД')
gtd_release_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата выпуска ГТД')
gtd_number = models.CharField(verbose_name='Номер ГТД', max_length=30)
rw_departure_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата отгрузки на ж/д')
rw_arrival_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата прибытия по ж/д')
warehouse_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата доставки на склад')
```

## forms.py

```
from MainApp.models import *
from django import forms
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
from django.forms.widgets import *


OrderFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Container, Order, fields=('order_date', 'ready',))


class AddOrder(forms.ModelForm):
partner = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ClientCompany.objects.all())
supplier = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Supplier.objects.all())

class Meta:
    model = Order
    fields = '__all__'
    widgets = {
        'order_date': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}, ),
        'ready' : DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}, ),
        'shipping_date': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
        'departure_date': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
        'port_arrival_date': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
        'documents_get_date': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
        'gtd_date': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
        'gtd_release_date': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
        'rw_departure_date': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
        'rw_arrival_date': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
        'warehouse_date': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
    }
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import auth
from django.http import Http404
from MainApp.models import *
from LogistApp.forms import *


def add_order(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    formset = OrderFormSet(request.POST)
    if formset.is_valid():
        print('validno')
        formset.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    context = {'formset': formset}
    return render(request, 'add_order.html', context)
context = {'formset': AddOrder()}
return render(request, 'add_order.html', context)
```

## html

```
{% csrf_token %}

<table>
    {{ formset.as_table }}
</table>
```

На выходе получаем ошибку ValueError: 'MainApp.Order' has no ForeignKey to 'MainApp.Container'.

Как правильно использовать inlineformset для создания вложенных форм, когда использована связь many to many?

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с `inlineformset_factory` нужен `Foreign Key`.

Если вы так хотите использовать `inlineformset_factory`, можно сделать следующее:

```
class OrderContainer(models.Model): # модель связка
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    container = models.ForeignKey(Container)
```

Поправить `Order`:

```
....
container = models.ManyToManyField(Container, through='OrderContainer')
....
```

Наконец:

```
OrderFormSet = inlineformset_factory(OrderContainer, Order.container.through, fields=('order_date', 'ready',))
```

А вообще почему бы не создать custom field-ы в форме, затем перед тем как сохранить `Order` создать по полям `Container` и добавить его к `Order`-у?